# Why Google Recaptcha V3 loading twice in Nextjs 12 application?

Tags: next.js, pagespeed, recaptcha-v3

Hello Everyone,

We are using the react-google-recaptcha-v3 pacakge in our nextjs 12 application. We found that recaptcha loading twice while measuring our site in PageSpeed tool and also found that it is loading 3times in network tab.

In form page(this below code is sample one), we imported the react-google-recaptcha-v3 in nextjs 12 application.

```
import {
    GoogleReCaptchaProvider,
    GoogleReCaptcha,
} from 'react-google-recaptcha-v3';
<form>
<div>
<label>Name</label>
<input type='text/>
<div>
 <div>
     <GoogleReCaptchaProvider reCaptchaKey={process.env.RECAPTCHA_KEY}>
        <GoogleReCaptcha />
     </GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
 </div>
<Button type="submit" hidden variant="secondary" name="logSubmit" block className="text-uppercase">Save Address</Button>
</form>
```

Please let me know what made wrong in code so it has been loading twice or thrice.

Please check the screenshot
[image]

Please check the below screenshot of google recaptcha appears twice.

[image]